# No response from codeception

Tags: codeception

I am trying to run codeception against my Yii2 project. However, I can getting no response from the simplest command line invocations. The command just sits there, for hours, until I break it.

I have installed this codeception manually, using the official phar and placing it in my path. I also have a copy in my vendors directory. Both of them do no work.

```
#install
wget http://codeception.com/codecept.phar
cp codecept.phar /usr/local/bin/codecep

#any combination hangs
/usr/local/bin/codecep bootstrap
vendor/bin/codecept build
codecept run
codecept
```

In am running PHP 5.5, and installed the latest version of codeception from the project web site.

Comment: Use strace to see what it is actually doing:  strace php codecept

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Works now after a reboot. I installed many libraries and software- might be related. I will be deleting this issue

Comment: Actually I was wong about that. There is a serious bug with codeception. It will run for one test, then hang, until a reboot it appears. Not even calling codecept with no parameters helps.

Comment: If it doesn't even print the list of commands when executed without any parameters, then it is likely to be an issue of symfony/console.

Answer (score 0):

Can not speak for your specific installation of Yii2 (basic/advanced/custom/etc) but this works for myself and my team:

In `composer.json` of your project ensure the following lines exist:

```
"require-dev": {
    "yiisoft/yii2-debug": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-gii": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-codeception": "^2.0.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2-faker": "^2.0.0",
    "codeception/codeception": "2.2",
    "codeception/specify": "^0.4.3",
    "codeception/verify": "^0.3.0"
}
```

In a CLI client (terminal/cmd/putty) run `php composer install` from the root of the project and ensure the packages install. Next check inside the `./vendor/bin` dir in your project, do you see a file named 'codecept'? You should.

Next, check that `./tests` directory exists; again at the root of your project. Inside that should be a file called `codeception.yml` This is the main configuration file codeception uses the begin the testing process(es). Without it nothing works.

Back in the CLI client run `php ./vendor/bin/codecept run -c ./tests/codeception.yml`. In the worse case this should provide some output from Codeception.

[image: Example file structure]

Comment: Don't use  "codeception/codeception": "^2.0" - anchor a minor release, because there are incompatibilities between minor releases.

Answer (score 0):

Try: www.pceuropa.net/blog/yii2-tests-codeception-configuration-first-test/